# How to carry unit test on router function NodeJS / Mocha / Chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

How should it seems, if I want carry unit tests on this router :

```
router
.post('/set-permission', (req, res) => {
    Board.updateBoard(req.body)
        .then(resp => { 
            console.log(resp.permissions);
            res.json(resp.permissions);
        })
})

module.exports = router;
```

I have folder in project/test inside is file .js with required chai library. Now I should execute this function with parameter? But how? Could someone explain me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [chai.http](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-http) for this, which allows you to test HTTP apps. Just make sure to export your `app` as you already do.

```
// api.spec.js
const chai = require('chai')
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http')
const server = require('../app.js')

chai.should()
chai.use(chaiHttp)

describe('User permissions', () => {
  it('sets the user permissions', () => {
    // Notice we are sending the request to the `server` export instead
    // of a URL
    return chai.request(server)
      .post('/set-permission')
      .then(res => {
        res.should.have.status(200)
        // add more tests here as you see fit
      })
      .catch(err => {
         throw err
      })
  })
})
```

Also note that this more of an integration test rather than a unit test.

Comment: If I will move code to controller or function in other file, later using export. I dont have to use chaiHTTP yes? I can only call this function with parameter yes?

Comment: `chai.http` allows you to test HTTP requests. I'm not sure what you mean by `call this function with parameter`.

Comment: for example I have module.export.store = function(req, res) => {
res.json({'ok'})}     So i think i can on this example makes unit tests yes?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that pattern.

Comment: So u prefer about make all unit test on this chaiHttp yes?

Comment: This is not a unit test. This is an integration/API test. And yes, all my API tests use `chai-http`.